# Add TextBox Values to GridView in ASP.NET on Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am following below tutorial to [Transfer Selected Rows from one GridView to Another in Asp.net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Transfer-Selected-Rows-from-one-GridView-to-Another-in-Asp.net.aspx)

I am following this tutorial it working nice. 
        Now i have created some textboxes and one button outside the GridView and I want to get the data from textboxes and on button click I want that data to be inserted into gvSelected GridView2.How can i do this

Comment: may you share some code of what you have tried so far...

Comment: i cant share my code here it exceeds the limits.Hence,i have shared my code at https://codeshare.io/adEreG thanks in advance

Comment: You should only post the relevant pieces.

Comment: ok i will share my code

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ajaxcontroltoolkit for update panel in which you put gridview and on button click you have bind the data again and update the panel

Comment: i am new to programming i dont know about ajaxcontrltool kit.what is that

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
In Visual studio find nuget package manager and in that search for ajaxcontrol toolkit just install it than search for updatepanel gridview than you get idea to use it.